# Alarm Clock without Noise? To wake up in common sleeping rooms and airports without noise?

Tags: gear, sleeping

When I am sleeping in certain locations, for example waiting for a vehicle in a sleeping room or airports, I want to make no noise to wake up to my alarm bell. There is a dilemma because the alarm bell makes some 100DB and it pretty much gets everyone angry every-now-and-then. How do you schedule your waking times in such positions as silently as possible?

I have tried an audio player in my ears but I tend to drop the ear parts while sleeping. I have also wondered about electric shock alarm clock but not sure whether something as silent may work.

Comment: I feel your pain. I'm a heavy sleeper and it takes miracles to wake me up without a loud alarm clock, vibrating alarms on phones just don't work for me!

Comment: You can also ask your accommodation if they can give you a wakeup. Hotels usually will, hostels vary a lot. If you're sleeping in a dorm ask some of the other travellers if they are getting up early to wake you up.

Comment: ...just thinking aloud, what about some sort of irritation to ear with high-intensity light like ear-plug-looking thing? Well, I am just innovating: ear has a connection brains. There are products already that already keep you more awaken with lower intensity light (having some leds to ear) -- what about awaking you? Actually, I am quite surprised if mil purposes have not already invented something like this -- searching, this issue must have more usage cases (not just traveling although personally I would like to have).

Comment: The best solution might just be to get headphones that are less likely to fall off than whatever you're using right now. Consider jogging earbuds, earbuds held in with tape, over-the-head headphones secured in place with a hat, etc.

Answer (score 17):

Hire someone to come slap you at the designated wake-up time.

Comment: This is almost as practical as it is funny! (-:

Answer (score 15):

I have a crappy old mobile phone that doesn't even work as a phone but it's handy as an addressbook and of course an alarm clock. And like most phones for years no matter how cheap and crappy it has a silent vibration setting.

Don't you have a phone? Doesn't it have a silent vibrating alarm?

Answer (score 12):

There are wristwatches with vibration alarm, these might work for you.

Answer (score 9):

Old Soviet-made alarm clock:

[image]

I removed some parts, so it can't ring, but it have vibro :)
It really helps to wake up quickly.
I place it on my back, under my clothes, and there is no way to miss its signal.

Other variant - use the cell-phone with good vibro-signal same way.
It is noiseless and quick way to wake up.

Answer (score 3):

Put your phone in vibrate mode and put the inside your pocket (preferably tight jeans).

Comment: Who sleeps in tight jeans? :O

Comment: usually I travel in jeans and sleep in the airport during the travel...

Answer (score 3):

I own a "sonic bomb" alarm clock. In addition to a loud siren, it is also equipped with a vibration motor that goes under the bed. You can use one or both at a time.

Comment: By definition, isn't a sonic bomb a LOT of noise, and therefore not what was asked?

Comment: If you read my response carefully, i said you can use "one or either at a time".

Comment: Ah, you'd said "one or *both*" and that wasn't immediately clear on my first read.

Answer (score 2):

The "[Shake and Wake](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0027A573Q)" looks to be one practical solution to this:

> ...wakes you on time every time, without disturbing others! You
>   need to get up at 6, but your spouse begins the day at 7. With the
>   Shake-n-Wake zzZ, you can start your day without inconveniencing loved
>   ones! Wristwatch-style alarm clock is able to be worn conveniently and
>   comfortably on the wrist. Instead of emitting a loud and annoying beep
>   to tell you it's time to get up, it vibrates gently but firmly, waking
>   you up the easy way... while letting others catch a few more winks.
>   Innovative and effective! Rise and shine: Comfortable and lightweight
>   to wear; One-touch backlight lets you see what time it is, even in the
>   middle of the night; Also ideal for reminding you of appointments,
>   medication times and more.